# How to POST an attachment(PDF) via Gatling?

Tags: scala, load-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

I'm trying to improve a script that I already have for load testing with Gatling. The scripts consist in injecting data filling forms with different type of inputs(dropdowns, textboxes, checkboxes, etc..). Now I have a form to upload attachments and I am trying to POST a PDF file but I have not found a way to do it.

If a open the network in the browser developer tools and upload the file and continue to the next form this is what I get:

1- First POST is when I click on "Choose File"

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

2- The second POST is when the file is already uploaded and I click on "Save & Continue"

[image]

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something very wrong, this is the .exec I'm currently have

```
.exec(http("Upload the file")
            .post("/private/private/private/forms/submit")
            .headers(shared_headers)
            .formParamMap(Map(
                "resumableChunkNumber" -> "1",
                "resumableChunkSize" -> "1048576",
                "resumableCurrentChunkSize" -> "10080",
                "resumableTotalSize" -> "10080",
                "resumableType" -> "application/pdf",
                "resumableFilename" -> "Caso_SimuladoSC_202.pdf",
                "resumableRelativePath" -> "Caso_SimuladoSC_202.pdf",
                "resumableTotalChunks" -> "1"))
            .bodyPart(RawFileBodyPart("file", "Caso_SimuladoSC_202.pdf")
                .fileName("Caso_SimuladoSC_202.pdf")
                .transferEncoding("binary")).asMultipartForm
                )// end exec
```

The PDF file is in my Gating repo with another files.

How can I achieve this? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Answered on [Gatling's community forum](https://community.gatling.io/t/how-to-post-a-form-signed-with-aws-signature-v4-via-gatling/6912/3). This form is signed with AWS Signature v4.